# Login to a site and then POST to a page in it

Tags: bash, cookies, curl, http-post

I have to login to a page using three parameters, after that I have to POST two parameters to another page inside the site I've just logged in.

So far I've got a cookie with this:

```
curl -c cookie.txt -d "username=username&pwd=pwd&domain=mydomain" http://myurl
```

...inside of the cookie I have a JSESSION id.
I use the cookie as follows:

```
curl -b cookie.txt -d "par=value" http://myurlnumbertwo
```

Problems:

- even after a POST to the login url I get in the console the HTML code of the login page, does this mean that the login did not succeed? How can I find the error that caused this, maybe a log?
- after a successful login how do I remain in the login session and POST my parameters to the other page?

EDIT:

I finally got this working after stran's hint, follows the code.

- POST_DATA contains the exact encoded string that was posted, as in 'parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2'
- ACTION_URL contains the full URL to which the form is posted, as in https://stackoverflow.com/users/login

First I did a

```
wget --save-cookie cookie.txt --post-data 'POST_DATA' ACTION_URL
```

to make the login and save the cookie, followed by a:

```
wget --load-cookie cookie.txt --post-data 'POST_DATA' ACTION_URL
```

to make the POST I needed, thank you again for the hint ^^

Comment: How are you trying to use the cookie afterwards?

Comment: Edited the question after seeing your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd give wget a try. There is a `--save-cookies` and `--load-cookies` option that allows you to use a cookie file. There's also a facility for handling session cookies, `--keep-session-cookies`. Refer to the wget man page for more :)

Personally, I've had much better luck with post through wget.

GL!

Comment: Thank you so much for the hint stran, I finally got that working... I'll edit the post for the others... :]